# Grape entity empty active record array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api, grape-entity

I am using grape API and returning response using grape entity framework.

```
get '/' do
  users = User.all
  present users, with: API::Entities::UserInfo
end

module API
  module Entities
    class UserInfo < Grape::Entity
      expose 'UserInfo' do
        expose(:UserId) do |users, options|
          user.id
        end
        expose(:CompanyId) do |users, options|
          user.company.id
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Expecting an output if users present. Array of active record relations(This works out)

```
 [{"UserInfo":{"UserId":4848,"CompanyId":276}},{"UserInfo":{"UserId":700,"CompanyId":276}}]
```

Expecting an output if users blank. Empty Array of active record relations (**How to handle this**)

```
 [{"UserInfo":{"UserId":null,"CompanyId":null}},{"UserInfo":{"UserId":null,"CompanyId":null}}]
```

Comment: What is a "blank user", could you explain a bit more please? I can't understand what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: and how many blank users you want?